# "Had"(past perfect) then ''before''(past tense)

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

Let's say you are storytelling about your academic success to your countrymen. This goes as:

> "I **had** **thought** that, I already **had** good English communication skills before I **took** the exam, and the only thing that I **thought** I **had** to work on was the mechanics of the test. However, I was wrong, I still **had** a long way to go as I realized."

According to the aforegiven sentences, is the ***'sequence of tenses'*** clear and correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Yes, it's fine. aforegiven is a bit of a stretch. Given above is better.

Comment: It does not look fine to me. Both thoughts had obtained before the test was taken.

Comment: @JeffMorrow, Yes they are, that's what I'd like to say really. Is it ok now?

Comment: @John Personally I would write "had thought" in both cases.